# Regex to get only the text inside the double and Single quotes and the line number

Tags: c#, regex

Regex to get the text within the double and single quotes with line number.

For example:

```
line 123 Processing File "This is what i am looking for"<'this is also what i need'>
```

Output should be:

```
line 123 This is what i am looking for  this is also what i need
```

My regex is:

```
 MatchCollection matches2 = Regex.Matches(l, "\"([^\"]*)\"");

     foreach (Match match2 in matches2)
           {
                foreach (Capture capture2 in match2.Captures)
                    {
                        textBox4.Text = textBox4.Text + capture2.Value + Environment.NewLine;

                    }
            }
```

I am getting (my output):

```
"This is what i am looking for"
```

I don't need the double quotes, I need only the text within the quotes.

Comment: Would it not be possible to use `string.replace("\"","").replace("'","")` to remove the quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string input =
    "line 123 Processing File \"This is what i am looking for\"<'this is also what i need'>";
string output =
    string.Join(" ", Regex.Matches(input, @"(line\s+(\d+)|(""|').*?\3)")
                          .Cast<Match>()
                          .Select(m => Regex.Replace(m.Value,
                                                     @"^[""']|[""']$", "")));
```

Output:

```
line 123 This is what i am looking for this is also what i need
```

Comment: It works ..but i am also geting the text after the double quotes..**Line 283-//document.<getElementById(>"this text").style.display ="none";** i am getting output:-this text style.display=none thanks

Comment: Another simple question.What is regx to get the text witnin the double quotes.example:"I need this"Output:-I need this.I am getting:-"I need this"  Thanks

Comment: I don't get that result. It works for me. The second regex in the sample is what removes the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue here is that you are looking at the match rather than the captures. The captures will show you the stuff gathered by the ( ) operators.

```
matches2.OfType<Match>().Select(x => x.Captures[0].Value)
```

Comment: can u pls give the regex pattern to get the single and double quotes.And how can i get the line number ?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Regex.Replace(inputtext, @"line (\d+).*?\""(.*?)""\W+(.*?)'", "line $1 $2 $3")
```